# D3 + VueJs + Typescript | Fixing Errors

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js, vuejs2

I am trying to make work VueJS with Typescript and D3.js library.

I have managed to display a graph but Typescirpt gives me loads of errors

This is my code:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import { Component } from 'vue-property-decorator';

import * as d3 from "d3";
import * as d3select from 'd3-selection';

@Component
export default class HomeComponent extends Vue {

name: 'non-vue-line-chart'
data() {
    return {
        chartData: [99, 71, 78, 25, 36, 92],
        line: '',
    };
}

getScales(){
    const x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, 430]);
    const y = d3.scaleLinear().range([210, 0]);
    d3.axisLeft().scale(x);
    d3.axisBottom().scale(y);
    x.domain(d3.extent(this.data().chartData, (d, i) => i));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(this.data().line, d => d)]);
    return { x, y };
}

calculatePath() {
    const scale = this.getScales();
    const path = d3.line()
        .x((d, i) => scale.x(i))
        .y(d => scale.y(d));
    this.data().line = path(this.data().chartData);
}

mounted() {
    this.calculatePath();
  }
}
```

This is the list of errors I get: [List of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pD4w.png)

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./ClientApp/components/home/home.ts:23:9 
TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./ClientApp/components/home/home.ts:24:9 
TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./ClientApp/components/home/home.ts:25:18 
TS2345: Argument of type '[undefined, undefined] | [number, number]' is not 
assignable to parameter of type '(number | Date | { valueOf(): number; })
[]'.
Type '[undefined, undefined]' is not assignable to type '(number | Date | { 
valueOf(): number; })[]'.
Types of property 'push' are incompatible.
  Type '(...items: undefined[]) => number' is not assignable to type 
'(...items: (number | Date | { valueOf(): number; })[]) => number'.
    Types of parameters 'items' and 'items' are incompatible.
      Type 'number | Date | { valueOf(): number; }' is not assignable to 
 type 'undefined'.
        Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
```

**Any advice and solutions?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @another-guy Sorry for not up voting your previous answer. I am very new to Stack overflow and I have not enough 'reputation points' to do it. I have accepted your previous answer. Meanwhile, I am trying to fix current issue. After fixing naming I still getting errors. The line 'd3.axisLeft' is being underlined. It does not picking it up in the class. When I type outside the class intellisense picks it up but not inside the class. Is it something to do with '.. class .. extends Vue'?

Comment: I'll take a look when I'm at my desktop sir

Comment: Thank you! looking forward to hearing from you. Best

Comment: I have updated the naming and added some errors. I cannot put all of them as editor complaining about to much code :( I have go 6 errors overall at the moment

Comment: I don't know how exactly you ended up having that many errors. I think you should provide a plunker... (I will post what I did in my case...)

Comment: I am getting underlined 'axisBottom', 'axisLeft', 'd3.extent'. It seems to be functionality of d3v4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not have `vue-cli` on my desktop, so:

```
npm install --global vue-cli
```

Then scaffold an empty project:

```
vue init webpack vuejs-d3  # Picked all defaults except of ESLint preset -- Airbnb
cd vuejs-d3
npm install
npm install d3 --save
npm install @types/d3
```

Then went to the **`HelloWorld.vue`** and moved your code into it and modified things *very* slightly. Notice, I'm using the **`*.vue`** file, because I like to deal with whatever Vue's defaults are. Nevertheless, type support works...

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <div>{{ chartData }}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import * as d3 from 'd3';

export default {
  name: 'non-vue-line-chart',
  data() {
    return {
      chartData: [99, 71, 78, 25, 36, 92],
      line: '',
    };
  },


  getScales() {
    const x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, 430]);
    const y = d3.scaleLinear().range([210, 0]);
    d3.axisLeft().scale(x);
    d3.axisBottom().scale(y);
    x.domain(d3.extent(this.data().chartData, (d, i) => i));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(this.data().line, d => d)]);
    return { x, y };
  },

  calculatePath() {
    const scale = this.getScales();
    const path = d3.line()
      .x((d, i) => scale.x(i))
      .y(d => scale.y(d));
    this.data().line = path(this.data().chartData);
  },

  mounted() {
    this.calculatePath();
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
h1, h2 { font-weight: normal; }
ul { list-style-type: none; padding: 0; }
li { display: inline-block; margin: 0 10px; }
a { color: #42b983; }
</style>
```

When I run `npm run dev`, I do not see any compilation errors neither in the Git bash

[image: npm run dev output]

nor in VS Code (with [*Vetur*](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=octref.vetur) plugin installed) when I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>

[image: Ctrl+space view]

nor when I hover the cursor over the methods

[image: cursor hover view]

---

P.S. Below are the package versions I'm tested against.

Global:

```
vue-cli@2.9.1
```

From `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
  "d3": "^4.11.0",
  "vue": "^2.5.2",
  "vue-router": "^3.0.1"
},
```

---

Since I was unable to reproduce your issue, I **strongly** recommend you create a plunker or any other tangible repro people can play with. Right now, it's hard to see what's wrong with your stuff. Sorry. If you follow my steps, things *should just work*.